# PowerShell module installed manually. cmdlets found with help but not recognized when executed

Tags: powershell, installation, module, solarwinds-orion

I have a machine i would like to install a module on, specifically SwisPowerShell for working with SolarWinds. Internet is disabled on it so i cant use install-module, so i manually downloaded the .nupkg from another machine and went through the steps of unpacking the files into the correct folders. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7.2. all the .dll files and the windows powershell datafile i have tried in both directories "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SwisPowerShell\3.1.0.343" and "C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SwisPowerShell\3.1.0.343". Importing the module with "import-module -name SwisPowerShell -Global -force -Verbose" shows that everything loads correctly, but then running "get-module SwisPowerShell -Verbose" returns nothing. even loading each dll individually with "add-type -path "C:...\somefile.dll" shows nothing. running "get-module -ListAvailable" shows the module in both (or either) directories as they should be. using "get-help cmdletname" and "get-command cmdletname" shows the correct cmdlet definitions. trying to run any of the cmdlets returns "The term 'connect-swis' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function... yada yadda" for all of the cmdlets. its like powershell sees the files but refuses to use them. Am i missing a step that tells powershell that this is a valid module to use? could it be blocked somehow? what extra steps does install-module do that a manual install does not that i could try?

Comment: I dunno about this specific module but generally I'd just use Save-Module and then copy that folder to my target machine instead of going down the nupkg-route.

Answer (score 0):

Try running process monitor while installing on another machine.  You might find out it's doing some registry changes too.